# Designing backend software for multiplayer cross platform app

Tags: django, api, backend

I am currently in the initial design phase of my first app.

In my app there will be individual sessions containing 1-5 users.

I need to be able to keep track of each users gps location and be able to push and pull them to each of the users. Each user will have the most recently reported location of every other user in the session.

There will be other calculations done on the data set but that will be client side, the server should only need to handle pushing and pulling of user locations (and the usernames).

I'm predicting due to the nature of the app 90% of sessions should not last more than 2 hours, with the possibility of the server ending sessions that are older then 24-48 hours (once real world testing of the app begins I would have a better idea of how long sessions should last).

I was thinking of using django to build an API, and to store all the data in the program itself and not to use a database as this should be faster and I don't think it is necessary to store the data since it has such a short lifetime.

Is this a good starting point? Is there anything I should be thinking about or considering? I'm completely new to designing backend software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While performance might not even be an issue in the beginning, there are some things you can do once you hit a certain load:

- Keep all your session data in one model, even if you're denormalizing (putting redundant information into your database) your database a bit. That way you only have to do one read to the database and no expensive JOINs
- Use the Django caching framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) to cache views, so multiple reads of the same data don't have to hit the database
- Before you start optimizing, profile your code to see where your performance bottlenecks really are. Sometimes you'll be surprised which operations are expensive, and which aren't.